# Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Duplicate Symbols. I renamed my project and this happened

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I've been reading up on various linker errors on Stack Overflow for awhile now, and each seem to be a bit different. I'm hoping you might have insight into the one I'm getting.

I've got the following... (issue only exists in simulator. It's fine on device.)

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
ld: 192 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are 2 errors for every file...

```
duplicate symbol _CATEGORIES in:
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Roto_Forum-ahulcvyneocizdcbjsdtiqgknlhk/Build/Intermediates/Roto Forum.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Roto Forum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FFFMainBodyViewController.o
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Roto_Forum-ahulcvyneocizdcbjsdtiqgknlhk/Build/Intermediates/Roto Forum.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Roto Forum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Item.o

duplicate symbol _POINTS in:
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Roto_Forum-ahulcvyneocizdcbjsdtiqgknlhk/Build/Intermediates/Roto Forum.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Roto Forum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FFFMainBodyViewController.o
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Roto_Forum-ahulcvyneocizdcbjsdtiqgknlhk/Build/Intermediates/Roto Forum.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Roto Forum.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Item.o
```

That's 2 of the 192 errors. If I look at my Compile Sources under the Build Phases of my Target, FFFMainBodyViewController.m is the first file. Item.m is the second. And for each and every file down the list, in order, I get a 2 duplicate errors like the ones seen above.

This all started I believe when I renamed my project, and therefore the target name in my Podfile also changed.

I've tried various things. Deleting Derived Data, Cleans, deleting the red libPods.a file from my framework, etc.

How might I solve this issue?

Comment: Do those two .m files import a common .h file and does the .h file declare a non-external global?

Comment: @rmaddy  None import a common .h. I get the above 2 instances for literally every file in my project. The 192 errors. I have variables out like there `static NSInteger const ABC_SEGMENT_CATEGORIES = 0", and also XYZ_SEGMENT_CATEGORIES = 0 in a different file. Not the exact same name.

Comment: Are the static variables in a .h or a .m? If in a .h you will have problems.

Comment: @rmaddy They are all in .m's, but above the `@interface` ClassName () `@end` and `@implementation` ClassName lines. Is that why. Is that equivalent to them being in a .h?

Comment: No, that would be fine. Using static in a .m would not cause duplicate symbols.

Comment: @rmaddy It all happened when I renamed my project name, and changed my cocoa-pod target name to the new name at the same time. I didn't notice for awhile though as I was always using the Device to run on. When I switched to Simulator a few days later, I noticed the errors. My libPods.a file is red in my project. I can't seem to find it though, even after a `pod install`